# Windows 10 change user folders location on a NTFS mounted volume

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, folder-redirection

I have two drives, on the bigger one I have created a NTFS partition and mounted it on an empty C:\Home folder, and I have changed the location of user folders (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, ...) to this folder, so that I now have C:\Home\myuser\Desktop, and so on. 
Is this a Microsoft-supported configuration ? I am asking because it works from the GUI (even if I see duplicated icons for each relocated folder), but from the Command Prompt I cannot see anything if I issue a "dir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop" command.

Answer (score 0):

You have only changed the location of some sub-folders of your profile,
but the location of the basic profile folder didn't change,
so `%USERPROFILE%` still points to where it did before.

Windows is not intelligent enough to understand that it needs to do something
more for `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` than just textually substitute the value of
`%USERPROFILE%`.

For alternative methods to get the current location of such relocated folders,
see the post :
[Windows command prompt - Get relocated user's Documents folder](https://superuser.com/questions/1132288/windows-command-prompt-get-relocated-users-documents-folder).